# Typescript implements interface with 57 keys: use of spreadoperator?

Tags: typescript, class, interface

I need to create a class that implements a Interface with 57 properties (in fact this is a googleapi adminsdk schema).
I would like to avoid retyping the whole interface definition when creating the class.
Was thinking about using the spread operator, but it failed

Light example with only 3 properties:

```
interface myInt {
   field1:string;
   field2:string;
   field3?:number;
}

class theClass implements myInt{
   private theFields:myInt
   constructor(data:myInt)
   {
     this.theFields = {{}, ...data}   <---incorrect
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a few things are going on here.  Starting with your interface:

```
interface MyInt {
  field1: string;
  field2: string;
  field3?: number;
}
```

your original class was something *holding* a `MyInt`, it didn't really *implement* it.  The "right" way to hold a `MyInt` in a class would be:

```
class HasMyInt {
  private theFields: MyInt;
  constructor(data: MyInt) {
    this.theFields = { ...data }; // spread data into this.theFields
  }
}
```

Maybe that suffices for you, but then `HasMyInt` is not itself an instance of the `MyInt` interface.  If you want to make a class which is an instance, the "right" way to do that does unfortunately involve redundant property declarations, along with [definite assignment assertions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#definite-assignment-assertions) to suppress any warnings with `--strictPropertyInitialization`:

```
class IsMyIntManual implements MyInt {
  // need these, unfortunately:
  field1!: string;
  field2!: string;
  field3?: number;
  constructor(data: MyInt) {
    Object.assign(this, data); // spread data into this
  }
}
```

That uses [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) instead of the object spread operator, because it allows you to modify an existing target object (`this`) instead of returning a new one.

If you really want to avoid redundant property declarations, you can make a kind of "base class factory" which, given an object type `T`, produces a constructor function that copies properties from an argument of type `T` into itself.  Note that this requires a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to compile, since TypeScript does not recognize a ES5-style constructor function as `new`able.

```
function BaseClass<T extends object>() {
  return (function(this: T, data: T) {
    Object.assign(this, data);
  } as any) as new (arg: T) => T; // need assertion
}
```

This lets you easily create `IsMyInt` by extending `BaseClass<MyInt>()`:

```
// this implements IsMyInt
class IsMyIntAutomatic extends BaseClass<MyInt>() {}
```

And if you need to add more functionality to this class, you can do so:

```
class ExtendingIsMyInt extends BaseClass<MyInt>() {
  public anotherProperty: number;
  constructor(data: MyInt, anotherProperty: number) {
    super(data);
    this.anotherProperty = anotherProperty;
  }
  method() {
    return this.field2 != this.field1 ? this.field3 || this.anotherProperty : 0;
  }
}
```

[Link to this code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5kG8BQyyMwEANgCYCMAXMgM5hSgDmA3IcaZQEx2PMQ7TiXIUAzAH46IAK4BbAEbQOAX3z4EZOPXrIAEjozYweTgAdmANziRkYABYQAYtwr06x8ByIIA9iACsghgflAAFBS2cJ5Y4ACUZkREjsD0AHSOLm56ALx4yOlFUWBwyKo+5fjqmtq6yJj0XmCocHJwZMjA8uZkEPIQ4HrNScgA9GPIIBAQFPZO9BAANMiyIDBhYGu25Og0Im5UAIT8TKyVorwnDGdCF25SMgrKUJX+gUzBoRElMWhxYESBGSyAA8ooAFYQELpHT0YAsEDhVL0Fa-eKVdQ1GBrELAALIABCOggAGE6vQADwAFWQEAAHpAQO5kH5IdCwAA+cJAzhQCBbKAgZDhHEgPEBZEONJ0alo6Ky3kg8FQmFwhFIlHy0oYziqZA6A0gdCJQ3TADuIrgUBYiuQuU5yGpag0WjhDSaAIAgrJQvJbMAEHTGYMWcTFuS4ZTmtygTU3fUAKIh5msRojBlMsMkyO6aMA2OjcyyRRkQNGvxZKAABSgfnM0DAeymzxUnHeQRCYUiCv+JhWbUrThrdYbUCbTyU0CVyXosjHPZ1lRS0oyg6rtfrjfQ9orG9H28xnAGjj8FB5oyI-MFwpR6UuFB4yCO+TvD6oyEk8zS94eyAAPv+35riAQ7QJuY5NsgdAAAxHuoQA)

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your great answer. I was starting to develop the factory, your post will be helpful.